# In GridView TemplateField TextBox enter key performs like tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView that has a TemplateField in it, that has a TextBox inside it.  I found code that will allow the user to press enter and go to the next TextBox in the Grid just like the tab key would.  The only problem is that it's skipping the next TextBox and going to the TextBox after that.  It's weird it skips a TextBox everytime you press enter.  I don't know enough about Javascript to fix it.  Can someone look at m y code?

My Javascript:

```
function tabE(obj, e) {
     var e = (typeof event != 'undefined') ? window.event : e;// IE : Moz
     if (e.keyCode == 13) { // 9 for Tab and 13 for enter
         var ele = document.forms[0].elements;
         for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
             var q = (i == ele.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 2;
             if (obj == ele[i]) {
                 //focus TextBox on next row
                 ele[q].focus();
                 break
             }
         }
         e.returnValue = false;
         if (typeof event == 'undefined')
             e.preventDefault();
     }
 }
```

My GridView

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvPackRegular" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                                            CssClass="GridView" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                                                            <Columns>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Carton" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPackName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CartonType.Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartonTypeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CartonType.CartonTypeId") %>'
                                                                            Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPackQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Pack") %>' CssClass="SmallTextbox"
                                                                            onchange="invalidate();" onfocus="selectTextonFocus(this);" onkeydown="tabE(this,event)"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            </Columns>
                                                        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `i+2`

Change

```
var q = (i == ele.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 2;
```

To

```
var q = (i == ele.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
```